# Ability to use environmental variables in Feature and Scenario Names

Tags: karate

How to append Configuration variable in Feature name or in Scenario name. For Instance need to provide Info in reports based on environment run.
I saw there is an option available to add the Examples variable in Scenario outline name. on a similar note, do we have option to append Environment variable in Feature name?

Comment: by the way I don't recommend this. sometimes I wonder whether teams are interested in actually doing testing or looking at pretty reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in 1.0 onwards - if a variable exists in scope, it will be substituted in the Scenario name using the JS string interpolation syntax.

For example if your `karate-config.js` is like this:

```
function fn() {
  return { test: 'foo' };
}
```

It means that the variable `test` will be available when the `Scenario` is processed. If not, note that the test will fail.

So if your feature is like this:

```
Feature:

Scenario: ${test}
* print test
```

You will see this in the report:

[image]

So it is up to you how you set up variables in the configuration init.